# One controller with multiple directives/partials

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to use ng-model / my controller logic to do what I want. I will be using a partial/view in 2 places, one where I will use it once, and another where it will be loaded 3-4 times.

The issue is that I need to store the model with one entry, OR with multiple entries.

```
Single Page:
$scope.data = data;

Multiple Page:
$scope.data = [data, data, data, data];
```

How can I write my logic s.t. that I can write the partial once and use it in both circumstances?